# Accessing hreflang in a preprocessor or twig layer

Tags: i18n-l10n

How do I access this link in either the twig layer or a preprocessor in Drupal 8. I need to modify to edit the hreflang.  Thanks

```
<link href="http://www.drupal.com/au" rel="alternate" hreflang="au" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function MODULE_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
 foreach ($attachments['#attached']['html_head'] as $can_key => $can_value) {
       foreach ($can_value as $low_value) {
          if (isset($low_value['#attributes']['rel']) && $low_value['#attributes']['rel'] == 'alternate') {
             // Unset canonical tags if present there.
             $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][$can_key]['#attributes']['hreflang'] = 'your value';
           }
        }
     }
}
```